# Adding a Activity Indicator to the left of a tableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiactivityindicatorview

I currently have a table cell that can pan right to refresh content but I would like to add a activity indicator to the left in the white space. My cell is custom but I dont think you can add the indicator in the customcell.m because it only allows you to place subviews in the boundaries of the cell. Dont mind the text in the cells.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell's content view has the "clipsToBounds" property set to false, you could just add the activity indicator outside of the bounds of the cell's content view.  Perhaps in the x value of -50, or something along those lines.

Comment: Worked GREAT! I was really stuck here. Thanks!